# Android Authentication in App-Inventor to access Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-api, app-inventor

I would like to be able to access my google apps spreadsheet data from Android App-Inventor app without publishing to all. How do I set up authentication?

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution @DavidF? I making progress with using OAuth 2.0 in App Inventor and that would (probably... not tested) give you what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in case you are still looking for an answer, see here for an example with Google Spreadsheets http://puravidaapps.com/taifunGS.php and examples with authentication http://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#taifunOA
Taifun

Answer (score 1):

Here is a parsing tutorial I wrote a years ago:

https://imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/web-component-json-response-on-app-inventor/

Comment: has good examples. See if his pointer also gives you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

App Inventor does not support authenticating directly into Google spreadsheets.  You can use App Inventor's fusion tables to get a spreadsheet that supports authentication.

Import your spreadsheet data into a Fusion Table that authenticates with the same Google id that your App Inventor app uses.